# Changing thinness and form of a vertical line in a table

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, rules

I am trying to create a cover page, where in the middle of the page i use tabularx (tabular could have been just as well) to split the width of the page in to two parts.

I would like to know how could i control the thinness of the line?

I would like to make the line fading at the beginning and at the edges of the line if it is possible.

I have no problem to use tikz or any other solution, just the picture will be at the left side and my text at other side.

**EDIT**
I hope it is now clearer what i wish to do (to create the line in the middle which fades at the ends) Example:
[image: Example]

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use TikZ with a three color fading that you define using `\tikzfading{...}`. Here's something that looks like the example you posted:

[image: faded line in TikZ]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fadings}
\tikzfading[name=middle,
    top color=transparent!60,
    bottom color=transparent!60,
    middle color=transparent!0]

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\coordinate [yshift=-3cm] (base) at (current page.center);
\node at (base) [
    name=photo,
    inner sep=0pt,
    anchor=south east,
    shift={(-2cm,0pt)}
] {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{photo}};
\fill [black!70,path fading=middle, xshift=0.75pt] (base) ++(-1.5pt,0) rectangle ($(current page.south)!(photo.north)!(current page.north)$);
\node at (base) [xshift=2cm,
    anchor=south west,
    align=left,
    font=\Large
] {\textbf{Dominik Schr\"oder}\\
    Musterallee 21\\
    12345 Mustersen\\[5pt]
    Telefon: 01234/5678\\
    Mobil: 0110/123456\\
    E-Mail: dominik$@$schroeder.de};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code might help you for the fading part.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\sep}{0.025}

\matrix[matrix of nodes,text width=3cm,column sep=1cm] (m) {
blablabla&\draw (0,0) circle[radius=0.25];\\[3cm]};

\path [scope fading=south] (m.north) rectangle (m.south);

\fill[top color=black,bottom color = white]
    ($(m.north)+\sep*(135:1)$) rectangle ($(m.south)-\sep*(135:1)$);

\fill[even odd rule,top color=black,bottom color = white]
      ($(m.north west)+(135:\sep)$) rectangle ($(m.south east)-(135:\sep)$)
      ($(m.north west)-(135:\sep)$) rectangle ($(m.south east)+(135:\sep)$); 

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```